# What is an ad hoc test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

What is an ad hoc test?

What is opposite to an ad hoc test? How is it related to post hoc test?

I found it in [Goldfeld–Quandt test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfeld%E2%80%93Quandt_test)

> The parametric Goldfeld–Quandt test offers a simple and intuitive diagnostic for heteroskedastic errors in a univariate or multivariate regression model. However some disadvantages arise under certain specifications or in comparison to other diagnostics, namely the Breusch–Pagan test, as the Goldfeld–Quandt test is somewhat of **an ad hoc test**.  Primarily, the Goldfeld–Quandt test requires that data be ordered along a known explanatory variable. The parametric test orders along this explanatory variable from lowest to highest. If the error structure depends on an unknown variable or an unobserved variable the Goldfeld–Quandt test provides little guidance. Also, error variance must be a monotonic function of the specified explanatory variable. For example, when faced with a quadratic function mapping the explanatory variable to error variance the Goldfeld–Quandt test may improperly accept the null hypothesis of homoskedastic errors.

Comment: I do not know it "ad hoc test" has a special statistical meaning, but reading that sentence I would just understand that it refers to the fact that the test is usable only in certain specific conditions. *Ad hoc* is Latin for "to the purpose". Something made *ad hoc* is made for the specific purpose at hand.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @nico's comments. This is in effect an expansion of them.

1) Although *ad hoc* is academic or researchers' jargon, it should not be understood as a technical term. There is no precise definition (or antonym) to be discovered or found lurking on the internet.

2) Although "to the purpose" fits the Latin as well as any other translation, there is often a negative overtone in the way it is used which is dismissive, disparaging, deflationary, or deprecatory, whether in criticism of other people's work or (perhaps more commonly) of one's own work. However, this is not universal: *ad hoc* allows a positive translation such as "fit for purpose" (you read it here first?).

3) Commonly, a researcher would describe a test or more generally any procedure as *ad hoc* as a qualification to defuse possible criticism. The implication would be that although what was done seems appropriate in the circumstances, it should not be taken to follow from general principles or necessarily to have wider applications. There is often an implication that the researcher would willingly use a better-grounded procedure if one could be identified.

Examples often serve better than definitions. Faced with distributions that can be negative, zero or positive, and are long-tailed in both directions, I have used cube root transformations. There is no theory worthy of the name behind this; it just works well for those circumstances and can thus be described as *ad hoc*.

The connection with *post hoc* is a matter of a common Latin word, but there is no statistical link.

I know of no reason to hyphenate here: *ad hoc* and *post hoc* are the original Latin phrases which remain widely acceptable in academic and research literature.